# Translate "If any cat is shy, then it is not happy" into predicate logic

Tags: predicate-logic, word-problem

Given

- $C(x)$ is “$x$ is a cat”
- $S(x)$ is “$x$ is shy”
- $T(x)$ is “$x$ is happy”

translate the following sentence to predicate logic

> If any cat is shy, then it is not happy.

This is what I came up with

$$\forall x \left[(C(x) \land S(x)) \to \neg T(x)\right]$$

Seems correct to me but can anyone else offer some insight? Thanks!

Comment: Your translation is a great translation of "shy cats are unhappy", which is what I think your instructor meant. However, "If any cat is shy, then it is not happy" is not clear English (the referent for "it" is unclear - any cat? or the one that's not shy? Or just some impersonal "it" as in "if any cat is shy, then it is not raining"?). So I think you should moan at your instructor, if the problem was presented in English like this.

Comment: The problem was in fact presented like this Rob! Perhaps to confuse us!
Thanks for your input though, I feel more comfortable with the answer now.

Comment: ... and I should have said that your instructor could (rightly) reply that he/she chose a vague English phrasing deliberately to highlight how logical notation forces you to be precise.

Comment: The word 'any' is ambiguous. the clause "If any cat is shy" could mean either "If every cat is shy" or else "If some cat is shy".

Answer (score 1):

To translate this sentence, you can write ∀x ∈ C(x), S(x) → ¬T(x). I believe that what you have written is correct.

Comment: $C$ is a predicate, so $C(x)$ is not a set. And what would $\forall x\in C(x)$ mean anyway?